# Quartiles and appending elements to an end of a stack

Tags: queueing-theory

> The company at which Mark is employed has 80 employees, each of whom
>   has a different salary. Mark’s salary of $43,700 is the second-highest
>   salary in the ﬁrst quartile of the 80 salaries. If the company were to
>   hire 8 new employees at salaries that are less than the lowest of the
>   80 salaries, what would Mark’s salary be with respect to the quartiles
>   of the 88 salaries at the company, assuming no other changes in the
>   salaries?

The answer is

> The fifth-lowest salary in the second quartile.

This doesn't make sense.

Imagine the employees ranked in order from highest salary to lowest salary. If we add 8 new employees who have salaries lower than the pre-existing 80, then we append 8 salaries to the bottom of the list. How does Mark's position in the queue change? Shouldn't his position stay the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quartiles range from lowest to highest salaries (e.g., see Wikipedia's [Quartile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile)). Thus, the first quartile is the lowest quarter range of the salaries. As there's $\frac{80}{4} = 20$ salaries per quartile, this means Mark's salary occurs at position $62$, i.e., $19$ from the bottom. After adding $8$ more salaries at the bottom of the ranking, each quartile would now comprise $\frac{88}{4} = 22$ salaries. Thus, Mark's salary is now $27$ from the bottom, so it's in the second quartile, being the fifth-lowest salary (i.e., since $27 - 22 = 5$) in that group.